# Kerastunner distributed tunning - how to tell to chief that the search is complete

Tags: keras-tuner

I would like to use `Kerastuner` distributed tunning and have followed the details outlined in https://keras-team.github.io/keras-tuner/tutorials/distributed-tuning/. However, all my worker nodes finish gracefully while my `chief` process remains running even when the search space is fully explored. Ideally, I would like to be able to make certain summary reports once **all the searches are done by the workers**. But, it seems that the chief process remains running even if the search space is fully explored. Is there a way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent [pull request](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/pull/325) that stops the server after the trials finished. You should update your keras-tuner version.

For example: `pip install git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner@master`